# Warning: Uninitialized storage pointer

Tags: storage

I am try to compute the baby step giant step algorithm to find the discrete logarithm.
But because of the warning I can't compile the code.
It appears at the uint256[] storage A and uint256[] storage B

Here is the code:

```
function squareRoot(uint256 x) public returns (uint256 y) {
    uint256 z = (x + 1) / 2;
    y = x;
    while (z < y) {
        y = z;
        z = (x / z + z) / 2;
    }
}

function ceiling(uint256 a) constant returns (uint256) {
    return (a / 1) * 1;
}

function proofOfWorkOptimized() onlyOwner public {
    uint256 base = 19;
    uint256 exponent;
    uint256 modulo = 221;
    uint256 valueAtIndexi;
    uint256 valueAtIndexj;

    uint256 rootCeiling = ceiling(squareRoot(modulo));

    uint256[] storage A;
    uint256[] storage B;

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= rootCeiling; i++){
        uint256 result = base**i % modulo;
        A.push(result);
    }
    for (uint256 j = 0; j < rootCeiling; j++){
        result = base**(rootCeiling*j) % modulo;
        B.push(result);
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= A.length-1; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= B.length-1; j++){
            if (i == j){
                valueAtIndexi = A[i];
                valueAtIndexj = B[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    exponent = ((valueAtIndexj + 1)*rootCeiling - valueAtIndexi) % modulo;
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a little tricky. Unless you have a genuine reason not to, then you should declare `A` and `B` as memory, not storage. As it stands, your code writes 28 times to storage, which would cost 28 * 20,000 = 560,000 gas, a huge amount. Putting the arrays in memory would be substantially more efficient.

Declare A and B [thus](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays):

```
uint256[] memory A = new uint256[](rootCeiling);
uint256[] memory B = new uint256[](rootCeiling);
```

To write to A and B as memory arrays, you can't use `push`. Just do this:

```
A[i-1] = result;
....
B[j] = result;
```

Incidentally, the nested loop doesn't use the `[0]` indices of the arrays; you probably don't need to compute them if that's correct.

Disclaimer: the above is untested (but it does compile), so E&OE.

P.S. If you genuinely want `A` and `B` to be in storage, just move the declarations outside of function scope into the main body of the contract and drop the `storage` declaration (it is implied):

```
Contract Foo {
    uint256[] A;
    uint256[] B;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I tried both versions you recommended, using storage costs indeed a huge amount of gas, so i'll go with memory!
Thanks again!

Comment: Hi may I know why I got extreme high gas 500k after using your suggestion? Please have a look. Thank you: bool[] memory boolArray;
for (uint i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++) {
    if (getBool(toArray[i])) {
        boolArray[i] = transfer(toArray[i], amountArray[i], data);}}

Comment: @Russo, how long is your array length?

Comment: I think it was about 7 or so...